# Class wont generate ID using a while Loop

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i am trying to do a simple increment in Java and i get this 'Unreachable statement' in my netbeans compiler and i dont seem to understand what the worry is actually.

My code looks thus

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Thanos
 */
public class PersistenceClass {

    public static String getPersistenceID()
    {
        int startNum = 1;
        while(true)
        {
            startNum++;
        }
        String finalNum = String.valueOf(startNum); //<----- Says unreachable statement here
        return finalNum;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        getPersistenceID();
    }
}
```

Shows unreachable statement at some point where i try to convert from int to String.

Comment: because your loop is infinite. It will never reach anything which is declared after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

while(true) makes the statement below the loop unreachable. You should have a condition that will exit the loop after required number of iterations. For ex: while(startNum<100).

Supposing that you have this method to generate ID while persisting data in the table, i will have write something like this,

```
int static startNum = 1;

 public static String getPersistenceID()
    {
        startNum+=1;
        return startNum+"";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not exit statement in your loop. This while loop execute forever. It will not reach anything after while loop.